# Chile Tourist Visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, chile

I am a Bangladeshi studying in USA. Currently, I am ob F1 visa here. Recently, me and my wife got tourist visa for Chile. We are travelling from December 24 to January 7. We are flying into Chile at Santiago and flying out from Chile at Punta Arenas. We also plan to visit Argentina in between. When applying for Chile visa, we gave them our full itinerary along with our ticket. In the visa application, they asked how many days we will spend in Chile. We thought that it was the actual number of days we would spend Chile and we gave this 8 as per our itinerary. We did not at that time it means actual entry-exit time. When they approved our visa, they gave the visa validity for 8 days. This does not even cover our flight dates. Can anyone suggest what we can do now? Will they extend this at Santiago airport if we explain and show our return ticket there?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the embassy that issued your visa?

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately to report the error. Do not wait even one more minute.

Comment: The consulate at Washington DC just told us they can't do anything as they do not process the visa, they only print the stamp.... :(.  He then suggested airport police officer might be able to extend it but going through lots of reference online, it doesn't seem so.